# Close modal callback handler not invoked when CSS transition rule is present

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, css-transitions

I’m facing a really weird issue and I might use some help.

I have a modal that has its dimensions updated when my request completes, and I added a CSS transition to it, for when the height updates.

This is the rule I added:

```
transition: height 0.2s ease-out;
```

The component (the modal) has a close handler (`onClose`). While debugging I'm able to see that the events are being attached, however, when I trigger the close action (by clicking on the <kbd>X</kbd> button or clicking outside the modal), the close callback is not executed.

The weird thing is: If I remove the transition rule, the close callback is invoked normally.

Have you seem something like this before? Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that the height of the element you’re trying to click on is zero? If so, it would make sense because there wouldn’t be any clickable area to trigger the event.

Comment: Even if you can see the element, it doesn’t mean it’s height is a non-zero value. Sometimes a child element bleeds over the edges and makes it look like there is a non-zero height.

Comment: thanks for your comment @DanMullin , but the element height and width are there. Its also z-positioned, so I dont believe this is the problem here.

Comment: Are you using any floated elements?

Comment: If you’re not aware, floated elements do not add to the height of their parent container. Not necessarily part of the issue here, but good to know.

Comment: On a side note: you could try transform: scale(0) or scale(1) instead of the height property.

Comment: The problem here is I open the container with height X, and depending on the content size I update the height to match that size. I'm not showing/hiding the element

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example for us?